# Problemas para no mostrar las primeras tres notas destacadas con Query en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, wordpress-plugin

Estoy haciendo este sitio [web](http://qkstudiodemo.com/fundacionlomanegra/web/novedades/) donde tengo tres notas destacadas y por debajo el resto de las notas subidas, lo que quisiera hacer es que en las de abajo no me muestre las que ya están arriba, que no las repita. El problema que no se como usar la query para sacarlas.

```html
<!-- NOTAS DESTACADAS -->
            <?php 
                $home_args = array(
                'post_type'   =>  'post',
                'meta_query' => array(
                  array(
                    'meta_key'     => 'notas_destacadas',
                    'value'   =>  '1',
                    'compare' => '!=',
                    'orderby' =>  'meta_value_num',
                'order'       =>  'DESC',
                  ),
                ),
                
                'showposts'   =>   3, 
                );                
                $wp_query_home = new WP_Query( $home_args );

                if ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                  while ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                    $wp_query_home-> the_post ();
            ?>

<!-- NOTAS DESTACADAS FINAL -->

              <?php 
                  $home_args = array(
                  // 'post__not_in' => array( '1,2,3' ),            
                  'post_type'   =>  'post',
                  'orderby'     =>  'meta_value_num',
                  'order'       =>  'DESC',
                  'showposts'   =>   8, 
                  );
                  $wp_query_home = new WP_Query( $home_args );

                  if ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                    $counter = 0;

                    while ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                      $wp_query_home-> the_post ();
              ?>            
              <!-- fila 1 -->
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 lib-item">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> 
                      <div class="lib-panel">
                          <div class="row box-shadow">
                              <div class="col-md-4">
                                  
                                   <figure class="snip1208" style="width: 100%;">
                                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                      <!-- <img class="image img-responsive" src="images/destacada1.png" alt="..."/> -->
                                  
                                      <?php if(get_field('agregar_icono_a_la_nota')): ?> 
                                      <div class="date">
                                        <img class="icon image img-responsive" src="<?php the_field('imagen_icono_nota') ?>" alt="...">
                                      </div> 

                                      <?php  endif; ?> 
                                     
                                    </figure>                                 
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-8 lib-panel">
                                <div class="contenido">
                                    <div class="author">
                                        <span><?php echo get_the_date();  ?></span>
                                       
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php cortarTexto(get_the_title(  ), 300,"") ?>"><h4><?php cortarTexto(get_the_title(  ), 30,"...") ?></h4></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                      <p><?php cortarTexto(get_the_excerpt(  ), 100,"...") ?></p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                </div>

              <?php
               $counter++;
                if ($counter == 2) { 
                     ?>
                         <div class="clearfix"></div>
                         <br>
                          <?php 
                          $counter = 0;
                        }
                }
              }          
              ?>               
               <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según veo lo que quieres hacer es que los tres últimos post se muestren como destacados y todos los demás en la sección de más abajo.

Una forma de hacerlo podría ser indicando en la consulta que no muestre los tres últimos post, podrías modificarla así:

```
 <?php 
                  $home_args = array(
                  'offset'      =>  3,            
                  'post_type'   =>  'post',
                  'orderby'     =>  'meta_value_num',
                  'order'       =>  'DESC',
                  'showposts'   =>   8, 
                  );
                  $wp_query_home = new WP_Query( $home_args );

                  if ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                    $counter = 0;

                    while ($wp_query_home-> have_posts ()) {
                      $wp_query_home-> the_post ();
              ?>
```

Fíjate que he añadido el parámetro `offset`que sirve para excluir los últimos posts definidos en su valor, en este caso excluyes tres posts.

Comment: Claro!!! la idea es que los tres destacados de arriba no se repitan debajo también. que aparezcan solo arriba, por eso yo desde el back end le asigno con check que noticias quiero destacar como principal.

Comment: Hola ernesto perdona que te moleste, tengo un problema con esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151155/error-en-el-function-walker-nav-menu-wordpress no se si vos sabes algo de menu walker

Comment: Si las tienes marcadas como "destacadas" deberás modificar las consulta excluyéndolas. ¿cómo las marcas?

Comment: Ahí actualice el post con el que uso para destacadas.

Comment: ¿Las que no son destacadas tienen el valor 0 en el meta_key `notas_destacadas`?

Comment: claro yo uso 'meta_key'     => 'notas_destacadas',  lo que hago desde el custom con un ckeck es decirle ustedes desea destacar esta nota entre las tres principales.

Comment: Probé lo que me pasaste y se me rompió.

Comment: ¿has probado a modificar la consulta que utilizar para los posts destacados per combiándo el valor `value` del `meta_query` a cero y quitendo esto `'showposts'   =>   3` ?

Comment: y que le pondría? el meta_query en 0 decis?

Comment: Prueba y me dices

Comment: dale gracias Ernesto

Answer (score 2):

puedes filtrar el segundo query usando los ID's del primer query usando wp_list_pluck
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck

```
$primer_query_ids = wp_list_pluck( $primer_query->posts, 'ID' );
```

luego excluyes los posts en el segundo query añadiendo:

```
'post__not_in' => $primer_query_ids,
```

Comment: Y como lo usaría? porque no estoy del todo canchero con wp_query

Comment: agregas `$primer_query_ids = wp_list_pluck( $wp_query_home->posts, 'ID' );`  luego del primer `$wp_query_home = new WP_Query( $home_args );` y agregas `'post__not_in' => $primer_query_ids,` al segundo  `$home_args = array(`

Comment: Anduvo perfecto!!! Muchas gracias por el aporte!

Comment: Hola @aloMalbarez como estas? no se si podrás ayudarme con ese problema, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155838/hacer-query-en-un-post-trayendo-datos-de-taxonom%C3%ADas-de-otro-post-en-wordpress?noredirect=1#comment292478_155838