# Error en el function Walker_Nav_Menu wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, wordpress-plugin

Estoy intentando poner un menú personalizado con wordpress y estoy usando el Walker_Nav_Menu pero cuando pongo la función me salta un cartel de

**Warning: Declaration of BootstrapNavMenuWalker::start_lvl(&$output, $depth) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array) in /www/qkstudiodemo.com/htdocs/camconnection/web/wp-content/themes/camconnection/functions.php on line 212**

```js
class BootstrapNavMenuWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
 function start_lvl( &$output, $depth ) {
  $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
  $submenu = ($depth > 0) ? ' sub-menu' : '';
  $output    .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu$submenu depth_$depth\">\n";
 }
 function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
  $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
  $li_attributes = '';
  $class_names = $value = '';
  $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
  
  // managing divider: add divider class to an element to get a divider before it.
  $divider_class_position = array_search('divider', $classes);
  if($divider_class_position !== false){
   $output .= "<li class=\"divider\"></li>\n";
   unset($classes[$divider_class_position]);
  }
  
  $classes[] = ($args->has_children) ? 'dropdown' : '';
  $classes[] = ($item->current || $item->current_item_ancestor) ? 'active' : '';
  $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
  if($depth && $args->has_children){
   $classes[] = 'dropdown-submenu';
  }
  $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
  $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';
  $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
  $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';
  $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . $li_attributes . '>';
  $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
  $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
  $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
  $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
  $attributes .= ($args->has_children)      ? ' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"' : '';
  $item_output = $args->before;
  $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
  $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
  $item_output .= ($depth == 0 && $args->has_children) ? ' <b class="caret"></b></a>' : '</a>';
  $item_output .= $args->after;
  $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
 }
 
 function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {
  //v($element);
  if ( !$element )
   return;
  $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
  //display this element
  if ( is_array( $args[0] ) )
   $args[0]['has_children'] = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
  else if ( is_object( $args[0] ) )
   $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
  $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
  call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_el'), $cb_args);
  $id = $element->$id_field;
  // descend only when the depth is right and there are childrens for this element
  if ( ($max_depth == 0 || $max_depth > $depth+1 ) && isset( $children_elements[$id]) ) {
   foreach( $children_elements[ $id ] as $child ){
    if ( !isset($newlevel) ) {
     $newlevel = true;
     //start the child delimiter
     $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $depth), $args);
     call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_lvl'), $cb_args);
    }
    $this->display_element( $child, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth + 1, $args, $output );
   }
   unset( $children_elements[ $id ] );
  }
  if ( isset($newlevel) && $newlevel ){
   //end the child delimiter
   $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $depth), $args);
   call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_lvl'), $cb_args);
  }
  //end this element
  $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
  call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_el'), $cb_args);
 }
}
```

```html
    <?php
                 $args = array(
                   'theme_location' => 'principal-menu',
                   'container' => '',
                   'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav pull-right',
                   'menu_id' => 'nav',
                   'walker'  => new BootstrapNavMenuWalker()
                   );
                   wp_nav_menu( $args );
              
            ?> 
            
 <!-- ESTE ES EL MENU EN BOOTSTRAP QUE INTENTO PONER -->           
 <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li  class="active" ><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li ><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/quienes-somos">Quienes Somos</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown "">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Productos <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

  
     <li><a  href="vero/1/index.html">Vero Software </a></li>
  
     <li><a  href="solidworks/index.html" >SolidWorks </a></li>
  

    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="highlight "><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/soporte"><i class="icon icon-gear icon-spin"></i> Soporte 24/7 <i class="icon icon-gear icon-spin"></i></a></li>
    <li class="dropdown ">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Servicios <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/training-vero-software">Training Vero Software</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/implementacion">Implementación</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/consultoria">Consultoría</a></li>
     <li><a href="requerimientos.html">Requerimientos del sistema</a></li>
     <li><a href="ultimaversion.html">Información sobre la última versión</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li ><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/noticias" >Noticias</i></a></li>
    
    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/contacto">Contacto</a></li>

   </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece el número de argumentos que le pasas `start_lvl` no coincide con el de la clase padre.

Prueba cambiándolo así:

```
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        $submenu = ($depth > 0) ? ' sub-menu' : '';
        $output    .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu$submenu depth_$depth\">\n";
    }
```

Comment: Anduvo perfecto Ernesto! Muchas gracias!!!